# Kivy : [ERROR ] [AudioGstplayer] Resource not found

Tags: python, kivy

i'm pretty new to Kivy, when  I run this code, i get the error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/kid/.kiv /logs/kivy_15-08-30_30.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1-dev
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
[INFO   ] [AudioGstplayer] Using Gstreamer 1.2.4.0
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_gstplayer, audio_sdl2(audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
Sound found at a better day.mp3
[ERROR  ] [AudioGstplayer] Resource not found.
[ERROR  ] [AudioGstplayer] Resource not found.
Sound is -1.000 seconds
```

full code :

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

sound = SoundLoader.load('a better day.mp3')
if sound:
    print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
    print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
    sound.play()
```

Comment: You might have better luck on the kivy mailing list or irc for this one, I'm not sure about sound issues but other devs who've worked on it are more likely to see the question there.

Comment: I got the same error :) Please help

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your 'a better day.mp3' named file in your folder That's why it is showing that error, because it is unable to find that audio file (resource not found).

Comment: hi bro, tk u for reply, It've been a long time , so I don't remember it.
But how about

    [INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_gstplayer, audio_sdl2(audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
    Sound found at a better day.mp3